# Building a custom page for contract

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, custom-button

I have a requirement where I would like to create a custom button on the Contract object. My contract object has currently 50 fields in it. I would like create a custom functionlity where I have a button named 'New Contract'. This button appears on Contract record. If I go into one record and click 'New Contract' it should take me to a page to create new contract, but when I am taken to this new page I should see 40 of the 50 field value to be populated from previous record from where I was directed to this new page. 10 fields should be left blank. How can I achieve this using VF page? Would it be wasy to maintain the VF page if I add new fields in the future?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are there any specific problems you're encountering?

Comment: I do not know how to get started with this. Any heads up on a high level like create a controller and get the fields using xyz visulaforce component and etc etc would be great!

Comment: You should create a Visualforce page with Contract as a standard controller. You will need to write a custom controller extension that handles the population of the selected fields (could also mean emptying the fields that should not be copied). On the page you can use `<apex:inputField>` elements to show input fields for the fields you need.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to populate the field values of new record from the previous record?

Comment: Yes. If you use `<apex:inputField value="{!Contract.StartDate}" />` on a page with a standardController Contract, it will automatically populate the input field with the value of the record that's associated to the controller. You can associate a record by specifying the Id in the url.